# What profession would a person with super-immunity benefit have advantages in?

Tags: science-based, biology, society

In my fictional world, we have our John Doe (main character), an ordinary man who happens to be given a drug in the initial stage of testing that gives the user super-human immunity to biological viruses, bacteria and fungi. As an example of John's dramatically improved immune system, he is not affected by any current or in-development biological weapons (such as weaponized [Plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plague_(disease)) or [Anthrax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrax)), and common illnesses (Flu & the common cold) show no signs in his body.

To add to his advantage, no super-secret military or government organizations are aware of John's otherwise high immunity, so they are not pursuing him for his DNA. **So what would be a good profession for John Doe, in which he can take advantage of his super-immunity?**

Comment: Obviously he could be a health worker in an Ebola, Cholera, Malaria and AIDS-ridden third word country. Or a prostitute.

Comment: Please pick one between reality check and science based tags. They contrast each other.

Comment: @b.Lorenz - Or both!

Comment: He'd be really good at dying of things. Immune overreaction is one of the biggest killers of young (otherwise) healthy people. That's not to mention his allergies.

Comment: @b.Lorenz I don't want to steal your answer, but I did come here to post that...

Comment: Hard to see how a "drug" could give immunity to harmful biologicals but not kill off all of the symbiotic microbes in the human body which are essential for our continued health.  Even a distributed intelligence population of nanites would be struggling.  (Can ignore with handwavium, but makes it hard to have science-based answers.)

Comment: @Willk Helllooooo Nurse!

Comment: He'd be great at continuing the super-immunity research. He could also research bioweapons. But really, without a whole group of Johns, there's only so much he could do—everyone else involved in the project still needs the usual insane amounts of protection, and now they probably need to be protected from him as well. A field hospital does seem like a better use for him.

Comment: And then he dies of a [prion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion) desease :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A job in the medical field would be an easy choice, as he could offer treatment without fear of becoming infected himself.

However, enough precautions are usually taken by medical officials that he would be slightly convenient rather than game changing.  A better choice would be a medical investigator.  If a village or town suddenly starts reporting some sort of outbreak, he could easily see what the symptoms, contagiousness, and overall effect is without fear of contracting the disease himself (though he'd still need to be hosed down before returning to wherever he was sent from).

Another possible choice would be something in which being injured is likely.  Any cuts or scrapes are significantly less likely to become infected.

Answer (score 8):

If you want need some organization crippled by anthrax, and you don't have any suicidal fanatics, John is your only option.

If you *do* have suicidal fanatics, he's still by far your best option.

If you can afford him.

John is the only bioweapon suicide bomber ever who's learned from experience and become more skilled at it—because of course he doesn't die.

He's an expert in a field that doesn't otherwise have anyone beyond novices.

---

Admittedly this is a ridiculous idea, but if you could work up a story to make this bio-terrorist-for-hire into a plausibly heroic protagonist, I'd want to read it.